# MYSQL Error #1415 on Function Creation: Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Trying to create a conditional-based function that will return a result. I don't if it's the way I am setting the result value that is causing the error? Making MySQL throw the error code 1415 Not allowed to return a result set from a function.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION GetTechFull ( table_flag INT,person_pk CHAR(11) )
RETURNS INT

BEGIN

    DECLARE firstName VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE lastName VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE outputRes VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL;

    IF table_flag IS NULL OR person_pk IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    IF table_flag = 1 THEN
        SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(ResFirstName,1), " ", ResLastName) as name,ResPhone as telephone, TPGText as pay_grade FROM cs_sp.ww_techfull;
        SET outputRes =  CONCAT(LEFT(firstName,1), " ", lastName);
    END IF;
    IF table_flag = 0 THEN
        SELECT stdFirstName,stdLastName INTO firstName,lastName FROM student WHERE student.stdNo = person_pk;
        SET outputRes =  CONCAT(LEFT(firstName,1), " ", lastName);
    END IF;
    RETURN outputRes;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: If your `table_flag = 1`, you are not assigning `firstName` and `lastName` in the `SELECT` statement, and you additionaly get a `telephone` and other stuff that in a first sight make no sense too

Comment: You should select..into rather than select...; set...' which is nonsense in sql terms since the set cannot see the resultset from the select. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code has multiple problems, but the bggest ist that you a using a "normal select, which would return a result set, which is not allowed.

so oyu can only use, `SELECT .. INTO..FROM..WHERE` to get rid of the error message.

Iyour return Value doesn't correspond with the variable '`outputRes`they must be f the same datatype

MySQL 8 also wants a DETERMINIsTIC added

Below you see a working code sample, so that you can go from here, to whereever you want

> ```
> CREATE tABLE student(stdNo int, stdFirstName VARCHAR(64), stdLastName VARCHAR(64))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO student VALUES(1,'test2','testlast')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLe ww_techfull(ResNo int, ResFirstName VARCHAR(64), ResLastName VARCHAR(64)
> ,ResPhone varchar(16),TPGText varchar(64))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO  ww_techfull VALUES(1,'testfrist', 'Testlast','012345656778','Bad')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION GetTechFull ( table_flag INT,person_pk CHAR(11) )
> RETURNS CHAR(64) DETERMINISTIC
>
> BEGIN
>
>     DECLARE firstName CHAR(64);
>     DECLARE lastName CHAR(64);
>     DECLARE telephone CHAR(64);
>     DECLARE pay_grade CHAR(64);
>     DECLARE outputRes CHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL;
>
>     IF table_flag IS NULL OR person_pk IS NULL THEN
>         RETURN NULL;
>     END IF;
>     IF table_flag = 1 THEN
>         SELECT LEFT(CONCAT(LEFT(ResFirstName,1), " ", ResLastName),64) 
>         ,ResPhone  , TPGText 
>         INTO outputRes
>         ,telephone,  pay_grade 
>         FROM ww_techfull WHERE ResNo = person_pk;
>         SET outputRes =  LEFT(outputRes,64);
>     END IF;
>     IF table_flag = 0 THEN
>         SELECT LEFT(CONCAT(LEFT(stdFirstName,1), " ",stdLastName),64) INTO outputRes 
>         FROM student WHERE student.stdNo   = person_pk;
>         SET outputRes =  LEFT(outputRes,64);
>     END IF;
>     RETURN outputRes;
> END
> ```

> ```
> SELECT GetTechFull(0,1)
> ```
>
> ```
> | GetTechFull(0,1) |
> | :--------------- |
> | t testlast       |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT GetTechFull(1,1)
> ```
>
> ```
> | GetTechFull(1,1) |
> | :--------------- |
> | t Testlast       |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=81918ec2bd7d37a611e4b89f281e7e00)*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use common `SELECT` in a function which sends its result to the output stream. You must use `SELECT .. INTO {variables list}`.

---

You may do not use intermediate variable and apply `RETURN (SELECT {output column/expression} FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1)`. The parenthesis prevents the output to be sent to the output stream and converts it to scalar value. `ORDER BY LIMIT 1` usage is strongly recommended in this case, even when 1-row output is guaranteed now - it may become incorrect in future...

---

Your function does not process `table_flag` value other than NULL, 0 or 1 (which can be used, even errorneously). I'd recommend you to use something like

```sql
CASE table_flag WHEN 0 
                THEN RETURN ( {query 1} );
                WHEN 1 
                THEN RETURN ( {query 2} );
                ELSE RETURN NULL;
END CASE;
```